# how can i post to facebook application user's wall from rss link

Tags: wordpress, rss, facebook-opengraph

i want to make my facebook application post to users give it stream publish permission when a new post added in a rss feed / wordpress

Answer (score 0):

can only be done (rss feed to facebook) on a facebook page like what rss graffiti is doing

app posting to user's wall is more of a spam and facebook won't allow that, if it is - it would be in facebook dev documentation right?